# template using content type in drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

I am trying to develop a template based on content type. The scenario is that I need to fetch data from mysql and display it in a particular format on my website.
The things that I did were:

- created a content type called **faculty** and created a page in that type
- added a function called `render faculty` in `template.php`, where I fetched all my necessary values from the db and coded a template format
- added necessary styles in `styles.css`
- created a file called `node-faculty.tpl.php`, copied the `node.tpl.php` contents into the file
- added the following code in `node-faculty.tpl.php` to call the function from `template.php`

  ```
  <div class="content">
      <!-- <?php print "arg(0)=".arg(0); ?> -->
      <!-- <?php print "arg(1)=".arg(1); ?> -->
      <!-- <?php $id=$_GET['id']; print "id="; print $id; ?> -->
      <?php global $language;
      $content = render_faculty($id); print $content; ?>
  </div>
  ```
- cleared my cache.

According to my function, if I invoke the URL: `mywebsite/contents/faculty&id=36`, the page should get displayed with all the information fetched from db, but this is not happening.

Please let me know if anyone has faced this issue. I have been doing this for the past 4 days with no success.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question really needs some more background. Is there a reason for not using Drupal's standard way to get your node's data from the database (i.e. node_load())? Drupal has its own way to load and render content, which you seem to want to tamper with. Would you care to elaborate a little further what you want to accomplish?